# How do I make the ingredients in a burrito evenly distributed?

Tags: mexican-cuisine

I've been to countless "Southwest" Mexican restaurants, but for all of them except Chipotle, they just can't seem to get the ingredients in a burrito evenly.

For example, one burrito I had had all the lettuce up on the top, the rice was in the middle portion, and the meat I had was stuffed at the very bottom the burrito.

If possible, is there any way to ensure an even mixture of ingredients in a burrito? Is there a certain place to put these ingredients?

I'm asking this because it's one thing to have a poorly wrapped burrito, and it's another thing to bite into a huge chunk of pure guacomole.

Comment: In a burrito you're not making yourself, you mean?

Comment: There is nothing *wrong* with a burrito whose ingredients are layered.  This is how I make them myself.

If you desire a burrito whose ingredients are more evenly mixed, simply mix them together prior to filling and folding your burrito.        Am I missing something in the intent of this question?

Comment: That 'huge chunk of pure guacomole' is just a sign of sloppy preparation. The cook needs to keep their mind on what they're doing in order to make a decent burrito.

Comment: If I'm preparing it myself, I often run into the same problem. I put ingredients one at a time (I put rice first, then meat, then veggies, etc).   Having a burrito that isn't evenly mixed is simply disgusting.  I'm not sure about you, but who wants to bite into a mouthful of just beans, or just rice, or anything?

Comment: I really can't help responding to the subjective assertion: a bit of just one ingredient isn't exactly disgusting; all of the things in your burrito are things that people would eat on their own. But the question is still quite valid (if basic).

Comment: The same applies to burgers, but I don't normally see people eat burgers one layer at a time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To assemble a burrito:

## Traditional method

1. Lay your tortilla down on a flat surface
2. Spread a layer of the first filling (perhaps rice) down the center of the tortilla in a little row, about 1/4 the width of the tortilla, leaving about 1/4 tortilla width on both ends for the folding.  Something like this:

   [image]
3. Spread a layer of the second ingredient (such as beans) on top of the first ingredient.
4. Repeat step 3 with each subsequent ingredient.
5. Fold up the tortilla.

## Obsessive Method

1. Combine all filling ingredients in a bowl and toss, as you would a salad, until they are uniformly distributed.
2. Spread down the middle of the tortilla as indicated in the diagram above.
3. Fold up the tortilla.

## Tips for Success

Make sure the filling ingredients are suitable for being uniformly distributed.  For example, don't use large slices of avacado, use a dice.

## Folding

1. Take one side of the tortilla (as indicated in the diagram above) and fold it over the the edge of filling towards the other side.  It can overlap the filling and other side a bit.
2. Fold both the top and bottom of the tortilla over the filling at the edge of the filling.
3. Starting with the previously folded side, roll the burrito until it is a single role.
4. Place seam side down on the platter or pan you will heat it on, top with sauce or cheese as desired, and bake.

## Consuming Burrito

Eat it.  However you want.  Enjoy the variety of flavors and textures the distribution of the filling provides.

Comment: Dammit, now I want a burrito.

Answer (score 1):

I don't generally have any trouble just distributing things in a line from end-to-end, and most restaurants I've been to do that as well. For large burritos, this does of course mean that you'll have to take a few small bites across the cross-section to get some of everything, but that seems manageable.

But if having it really evenly mixed is important, well, just mix it before you roll it up. (And places like Chipotle will do that for you if you ask.)