# How to keep blintzes closed

Tags: baking, cheese

I am trying to make cheese blintzes. I made them out of egg and flour.

After packaging the blintzes up and readying to put them in the oven, they slowly start to pop back open. How do I keep them closed?

Comment: You may be overfilling them. If not, fry them on the seam after filling to seal them shut. It's how my grandma did it.

Answer (score 2):

If your blini are unrolling themselves, they may be too thick, and probably therefore need a higher proportion of liquid in the batter.   They should be thin, akin to western European crepes, and easy to roll.

The other possibility is you are trying to make very small blini, which would be more difficult to roll.  Generally, the crepe for each blintz would be about 6-8 inches across at the smallest

You then fold each individual blintz as you might a burrito:  see [How do I make the ingredients in a burrito evenly distributed?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/33609/how-do-i-make-the-ingredients-in-a-burrito-evenly-distributed) for a diagram and description of the method.

The initial fry seam side down should then seal them closed.

See detailed photos of method and sample recipe from [Shiksa Chick](http://theshiksa.com/2010/05/19/shiksa-blintzes/).